# Django create picture object based on upload_to and get response

Tags: django

I have this model and there is a ImageField with custom upload_to in it, so i want to create an instance and give the content of the file to my django model but i don't want to give any path or save image and i want django to handle this for me. this is the model:

```
class UploadSorlThumbnailPictureMixin(UploadBasePictureMixin):
    picture = ImageField(
        _('picture'),
        max_length=255,
        width_field='width_field',
        height_field='height_field',
        help_text=_('The picture that is uploaded.'),
        upload_to=category_dir_path,
        validators=[validate_file_extension]
    
)
```

and This is how i want to create instance:

```
response = requests.get(base_url) # this is the image content

UploadSorlThumbnailPictureMixin.objects.create(
    alternate_text=images['name'],
    picture='WHAT TO DO HERE?'
)
```

How can i get the image from response and put create the instance with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the image content with `response.content`

and to create an instance from it for imagefield:

```
from django.core.files.temp import NamedTemporaryFile
from django.core.files import File

img_temp = NamedTemporaryFile()
img_temp.write(response.content)
img_temp.flush()

picture=File(
    img_temp,
    name='yes'
    )
```